# Modifying the included auth controller for Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I am using the basic login and registration scaffold that comes with Laravel 5.3. I've also created a logging function so that I can log some of the basic user actions for my platform, such as updating or deleting records.

I'd like to add the logging to the user login process so that I can log when they've logged in and a failed attempt. Because I'm using the basic included scaffolding, I'm not sure where to do this?

Comment: Depending on what you need exactly if it is throttling user logins https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/configure-throttleslogins-variables-in-53 is a good resource.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hook into login process and just log something. Consider hooking into the authentication events provided by Laravel's [Authentication events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#events)

```
/**
 * The event listener mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $listen = [
    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogRegisteredUser',
    ],

    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Attempting' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogAuthenticationAttempt',
    ],

    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Authenticated' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogAuthenticated',
    ],

    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogSuccessfulLogin',
    ],

    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Failed' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogFailedLogin',
    ],

    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogSuccessfulLogout',
    ],

    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Lockout' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogLockout',
    ],
];
```